# Add a custom node group to all materials in the scene with python

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders

Is there a method that would allow me to to delete the existing Material Output node and replace it with a custom node group in every material in the scene? It would need to work with principled, emission and mix shaders.
I'm very inexperienced with Python so I don't even know where to start looking! 
Any help would be much appreciated!